# How calling the same dynamic google map in another position by link that opens a pop-up

Tags: map

I have a google map that opens in wp post pages, it is ruled by some functions, here is the main ones (I think I just omitted the save function):

```
function my_map_shortcode() {
$latitude = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'latitude', true);
$longitude = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'longitude', true);

if (empty($latitude) || empty($longitude)) {
    return '';
}

$map_url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAQGd95X0YBBzcLX4NwMeXEiCIjUy6dO4I&zoom=15&q=' . $latitude . ',' . $longitude ;

return '<br></br>Posizione su mappa<br></br><iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="' . $map_url . '" allowfullscreen></iframe><br></br>';
}

add_shortcode('my_map', 'my_map_shortcode');

function my_add_map_to_post_content($content) {
if (is_singular('post')) {
    $map = do_shortcode('[my_map]');
    $content .= $map;
}

return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'my_add_map_to_post_content');

function my_add_meta_box() {
add_meta_box('my_location', 'Posizione', 'my_location_callback', 'post', 'normal', 'default');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_box');
```

Now what I want to do is calling this map by opening a link, I click the link and this map opens in a pop up, how can I define the URL of this map when I set the link? Keep in mind that this map is in connection with post ID, every post has its map